# LINQ conditions from previous result

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core

I'm trying to write query to gets users by id from db (id are from the list) and second query to gets groups for first result query.

```
List<Guid> UsersID;
var users = await db.users.Where(user => UsersID.Any(i => i == user.Id)).ToListAsync();
var groups = await db.groups.Where(g => users.Any(x => x.IdGroup == g.Id)).ToListAsync();
```

First result is great but in second query i'v got error like this: System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression DbSet.Where(r => users_0.Any(x.IdGroup == r.Id). could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a from that can be translated, or switch client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable, AsAsyncEnumerable, ToList or ToLisyAsync
I'm trying to rewrite but I have no idea 'how'.

Comment: You need to show the full error message.

Comment: Separate out the `users` list from the users query, and use the query in the `groups` query with `Contains`.

Comment: Don't add it as a comment, [edit] it into the question.

Comment: Use a navigation property like `Group.Users` and you can do this much simpler in one LINQ statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting group ids into local collection and using `Contains`:

```
var groupIDs = users.Select(x => x.IdGroup).ToList();
var groups = await db.groups.Where(g => groupIDs.Contains(g.Id)).ToListAsync();
```